# A way to store static fields?

Tags: object, static, field

In my projects, I often have many static Objects of a class (let's say class A).
I create an additional class B to store the static Objects of class A, because else it would be too messy to store all static Objects in their own class:

```
public class A{
    public A(...){
    ...
    }
}

public class B{
    public static A a1 = new A(...);
    public static A a2 = new A(...);
    public static A a3 = new A(...);
    ...
}
```

Then I access these Objects with `B.a1`, `B.a2`, ...

Is there a better way to store a large number of Objects?

Comment: depends. if the number of objects is too large, then you can consider serialize them and deserialize when you need them

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit too general to answer.  Why exactly do you need these static instances?

If it's a small number of commonly used instances, it really makes the most sense for them to be within the class itself.  Look at [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), which has static instances for 0, 1, and 10 within the class.

Comment: The simplest example: I have an expression parser and I need a description for every function the parser can parse (200 functions). I could store a description of a function in a single string. So what would be the best way to store these 200 static strings?

Comment: Without knowing anything else, I would say that it should be a property of the function, if the functions are objects.  If the functions aren't objects, then what are they?

Comment: Yes, functions are also objects. But using a long description string in every function constructor would blow up the class storing functions - so I have to store these strings somewhere else